# Identity server stuck in redirect loop

Tags: redirect, identityserver4, bad-request

I'm using identityserver4 for single sign-on. For most of the time application function smoothly but intermittently we face a redirect loop issue which becomes a show stopper for us until we restart's our app service. The page goes on loading continuously before finally showing a 'Bad request - Request Too Long' page with message: HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long. If we check the network tab, we can see that the application is looping between the identity server and client application redirect sign in pages. The application insight tells us that the client app gives a 401 on his home/index page and then a 302 on the signin-oidc url, then goes to the identity server connect/token, then connect/userinfo endpoints to get claims and comes back to the client home/index page to again get a 401. The loop continues (Identity server says user is authenticated while client says it is not). We are unable to find a fix for this since long. Any help is appreciated. Attaching the client side configuration for reference.

### Findings

Our client app is an mvc app & we have used Session's & TempData in few area's. This areas are the triggering point of the redirect issue. What we have observed is, when the client initially login the authentication cookie is created (Cookie Name: AudDiscoveryAuth) and I could see it being passed in header for each request made to the controller actions. But once the user visit's any such area where we have used Session/TempData and Log out or any other user tries to login, Identity server successfully authenticates the user also the userendpoint to retrieve the details is being invoked however the cookie itself is not being created and is missing in every request to the Index/Home action method hence the redirect loop. Wondering what could be hampering in issuing cookie when using session variable elsewhere in the application or is their a setting missing.

Also in every redirect the occurrence of OpenIdConnect.nonce.XXX cookie is incremented. Once the count of OpenIdConnect.nonce.XXX reaches more then a certain level we get the bad request error page

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        string baseClientAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationUrl"];
        int slidingExpiryHrs  = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SlidingExpiryHrs"]);
        int slidingExpiryMins = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SlidingExpiryMins"]);
        TimeSpan expireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(slidingExpiryHrs, slidingExpiryMins, 0);
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationType,
            CookieName = "AudDiscoveryAuth",
            ExpireTimeSpan = expireTimeSpan,
        SlidingExpiration = true
        });
        
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthenticationPatched(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "ratingspro.web",
            Authority = IdsvrConstants.BaseAddress,
            RedirectUri = baseClientAddress + "signin-oidc/",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = baseClientAddress + "signout-callback-oidc/",
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = "openid api1 ratingspro.webapi offline_access",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationType,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = true,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                {
                    var client = HttpClientFactory.Create();
                    var tokenResponse = await client.RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
                    {
                        Address = IdsvrConstants.TokenEndpoint,
                        ClientId = "ratingspro.web",
                        ClientSecret = "secret",
                        Code = n.Code,
                        RedirectUri = n.RedirectUri,
                    });
                    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        LogHelper.LogMessage("RatingsproApp: Startup => tokenResponseError: " + tokenResponse.Error);
                        throw new AuthenticationException(tokenResponse.Error);
                    }
                    var userInfoResponse = await client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest
                    {
                        Address = IdsvrConstants.UserInfoEndpoint,
                        Token = tokenResponse.AccessToken
                    });
                    if (userInfoResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        throw new AuthenticationException(userInfoResponse.Error);
                    }
                    var claims = userInfoResponse.Claims;

                    if (claims.Any(c => c.Type == "ApplicationAccessDenied"))
                    {
                        throw new AuthenticationException(claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "ApplicationAccessDenied").Value);
                    }
                    // create new identity
                    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                    id.AddClaims(claims);
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("AccessToken", tokenResponse.AccessToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn).ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                    client.Dispose();
                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                            new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "name", "role"),
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                },

                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                    {
                        var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token").Value;
                        n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint;
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                AuthenticationFailed = x =>
                {
                    x.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "/";
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How long is the request headers? which header is too long? the cookies?

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: Hi @ToreNestenius, Thank you for taking time to check this :). Yes we are using Https. I was able to reproduce the issue and added my findings in the description area. Request you to check once.

Comment: Hi @ToreNestenius, Also in every redirect the occurrence of OpenIdConnect.nonce.XXX cookie is incremented. Once the count of  OpenIdConnect.nonce.XXX reaches more then a certain level we get the bad request request error page.